# Short url site API

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I have wordpress blog and I want to short all urls by this url shortner:
http://smart-gpt.com/short/api.html
And this is api code

```
API Address: http://smart-gpt.com
GET /short/api/v1/9f55f513858401acfd7d4a582715dd3c/shorturl/create/url/BASE64_ENCODED_LONG_URL.json
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use file_get_contents.
Example:
`$response = file_get_contents("http://smart-gpt.com/short/api/v1/c411262dba62021ece8e2244fc6ef212/shorturl/create/url/".base64_encode($longurl).".json")
$responseobj = json_decode($response);
$shorturl = $responseobj->data->short_url;`
That is plain PHP.
I don't know how to implement this in Wordpress.